# C++ Error in ' ' : free(): invalid pointer

Tags: c++, templates, free, abort

I've read through similar problems, but I can't find anything that specifically addresses my problem (or I simply don't understand the other solutions)

I am trying to implement a template Stack class, and am having an issue when trying to push to the stack. here is my Stack.cpp:

```
#ifndef _STACK_H
#define _STACK_H

#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Node.cpp"

template<typename T>
class Stack{
    private:
        Node<T>* mHead; 

    public:
        Stack();
        ~Stack();
        void push(T data);
};

template<typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack(){
    mHead = NULL;
}

template<typename T>
Stack<T>::~Stack(){
    delete mHead;
}

template<typename T>
void Stack<T>::push(T data){        // <-- having trouble with this method
    Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;
    temp->data = data;
    //if head is already empty, just create 1 Node
    if(mHead==NULL){
        printf("if working\n");
        mHead = temp;
    }else{
        printf("else working\n");
        //rearrange Nodes
        temp->next = mHead;
        mHead = temp;
    }
    printf("success\n");
}

#endif
```

push() gets called from a function in the manager class:

```
void Manager::testPush(){
    Stack<int> test;
    int number = 3;
    test.push(3);
}
```

When I run the code and call managers testPush() method, i get the following being printed:

```
if working
success
*** Error in `./assignment': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000f11078 ***
[1]    14976 abort (core dumped)  ./assignment
```

---

I'm not sure what free() means, and what could possibly be causing this error/abort

Comment: While fixing this, consider why you have an if-else in `push` in the first place. You don't need it. [Something like this](http://pastebin.com/K8vMK03s) will work, and fix your problem while doing so.

Comment: @WhozCraig I just tried your code, and it gives me the same error as above

Comment: [I beg to differ](http://ideone.com/rUMZ1i). If that code faults, then your doing something else wrong in your program. The link [**here**](http://ideone.com/rUMZ1i) leaves no doubt it does exactly what it should.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ah! my bad, I'm sorry I tried your implementation and it works... I was putting the node class in a different file. Is it better practice to put the node as a struct in the header file, or as a class as a seperate node?

Comment: it belongs in a header regardless (it is a template, after all). Whether it is integral with `Stack<T>` as a nested class or stand-alone is ultimately up to you.

Comment: @WhozCraig I've also noticed that you have declared your struct outside of the class definition. If we declared the node struct inside the class, would't it be private, and therefore safer/cleaner?

Comment: Honestly I only declared it like that because you had.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to set the data member `next` to `NULL` in node `temp`.

```
template<typename T>
void Stack<T>::push(T data){        // <-- having trouble with this method
    Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL; // <=== add this statement

    //if head is already empty, just create 1 Node
    if(mHead==NULL){
        printf("if working\n");
        mHead = temp;
```

If the class `Node<T>` has a constructor with two parameters or if it is an aggregate you could write simpler

```
template<typename T>
void Stack<T>::push( const T &data )
{
    mHead = new Node<T> { data, mHead };
}
```

Take into account that the destructor of class `Node<T>` must delete all nodes in the stack.

This function

```
void Manager::testPush(){
    Stack<int> test;
    int number = 3;
    test.push(3);
}
```

also looks questionably because test is a local variable of the function. The stack can be used only inside the function.

Comment: I'm not sure why I want to set temp->data to null after i've already set it to the passed in parameter data. (I want to create a new node, and fill it with the data passed into push)

Comment: @Vaderico You allocated a new node temp and set mHead to temp. So now mHead->next has some inderterminate value. This is valid provided that the constructor of Node<T> does not set this field itself.